# Winform has Red X exception

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I am using a 3rd party control (ComponentOne) and at intermittently I would get this typical red X box such as this typical image shows.  At first I thought I have a GDI leak, so after doing some leg works I verified my GDI numbers are fine when drawing controls.

[image]

After Googling around I found that this kind of error happens on the OnPaint() event and therefore even if i put a try and catch when calling the control to Render, it wont catch it.

So my next step is to have the following override in my code.

```
        protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
       {
           try
           {
               base.OnPaint(e);
           }
           catch (Exception ex)
           {
               this.Invalidate();  //attempt to redraw the control
               XmSam.Log(ex);
           }
       }
```

I think that should do the trick but I can't recreate this problem all the time and so I haven't been able to fully test the above code yet.   My question is, if I render my control and it has exception then this code will attempt to redraw the control.  Will this stuck in an indefinite loop and freezes my UI? or would you think whatever caused the exception will go away and upon the second control redraw and it should render fine?

Comment: It won't freeze your UI because `Invalidate()` only posts a redraw request to the message queue (roughly) and does not repaint synchronously. However, as you said, you may very well receive an exception on the second and subsequent redraws. I would suggest you investigate what that exception is and what is causing it.

Comment: You'll do better asking in the official support forum for where ever you found the control.

Comment: Something is null in the HeaderCell.Paint event.  We can't see it.

Comment: The stack trace says null reference. Make sure that everything is being filled in.

Comment: I have seen this on other third party controls and it has always turned out something was trying to use the control before it was initialize and offten treading is involved in a data load.

Answer (score 5):

> I think that should do the trick

No, you made it far worse.  Now your OnPaint() method is running over and over again, probably falling over on the same exception repeatedly.  You'll see your program burning 100% core as well.

Getting an exception in OnPaint() is not something you can really survive.  There's nothing to look at for the user, that's a guaranteed support call.  Instead of hiding the problem, use the exception to figure out what actually went wrong and **fix** the problem.  Use Debug + Exceptions, tick the Thrown checkbox for CLR exceptions so the debugger will stop when the exception is raised.  Just in case, it is not unlikely that the exception is raised in framework code, also use Tools + Options, Debugging and untick the "Enable Just My Code" option.

Answer (score 0):

When I have seen this in the past it always had to do with a threading issue.  Are you updating this control from a different thread than the UI thread?

Its been a while since I've dealt with that but I think the easiest thing to do is use the BackGroundWorker Class to perform background operations and update form controls.

[BackGroundWorker Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx?ppud=4)