# Why a control becomes crossed with red lines in C#?

Tags: c#, winforms

I am new to C# and I am using windows forms.

I have just finished developing an EPOS application. The application has about 50 `forms` and 100 `user controls` and each `form` and `user control` contains many controls (`button`, `textboxes`, `panels`..) and many of the controls have icons.

The application reads and writes data from/to SQL server. When I run the application for the first time each of the 100 `user control` connect to SQL server to load data. All the 100 `user controls` have the SQL query inside their constructor as following:

```
    SqlConnection MyConnection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
    SqlCommand MyCommand = new SqlCommand();
    DataTable DataTable = new DataTable();
    SqlDataAdapter Sql_Data_Adapter = new SqlDataAdapter();

public UserControl1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        try
        {
            DataTable.Rows.Clear();
            DataTable.Columns.Clear();

            MyConnection.Open();
            MyCommand.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM PizzaTable";
            MyCommand.Connection = MyConnection;
            Sql_Data_Adapter.SelectCommand = MyCommand;
            Sql_Data_Adapter.Fill(DataTable);

           //Do something with the DataTable (Ex: fill Datagridview)

            MyCommand.Parameters.Clear();
            Sql_Data_Adapter.Dispose();
            MyConnection.Close();

        }

        catch (System.Exception excep)
        {

            MessageBox.Show(excep.Message);

        }


    }
```

The application also uses many events (about 100 event subscriptions) and the application always closes the SQL server connections when it finishes using them.

The application and SQL server reside in a computer desktop (4GB RAM, Win 7). during the use of the application I show/Close `forms`, show/hide `user controls`, open/close SQL connections and make receipt printing.

-The issue:

After I installed the application (from `.exe` file) and when I run it, it works as I want with no errors but after certain time of using the application when I show a form (as shown in screenshot) and click on a button on that form the button become red crossed and the form freezes and I have to restart the application to use it again. This red cross happens to controls regardless of if they have an icon of not.

[image: Screenshot]

My question is: What is the cause of this red cross lines and form freezing? and how can I prevent this from happening?

Comment: You may want to look into task manager to see the resources you are using. Watch for numbers that keep rising, esp. the GDI resources.. But the question is really rather broad.

Comment: @TaW the computer has 4GM of RAM. do you think the application consumes all of the 4GB?

Comment: As an aside to your question, you may be *closing* connections (may be, not always - eg if an exception occurs) but you're never *disposing* of them correctly.

Comment: GDI resources are rather limited and are not part of the normal memory resources. Also: Maybe you keep adding event handlers and make the events run multiple times?

Comment: @ TaW I only add the event handlers once at the form contractor to make sure it only subscribe once.

Comment: The Red Cross of Failure is painted when a control's OnPaint() method throws an exception.  There is try/catch code behind this, intentional because such exceptions can get a programmer stuck pretty badly when they get thrown over and over again.  You have to find out what that exception looks like by forcing the debugger to stop on the "first chance" notification.  Disable "Just My Code" in the debugger settings and tick the Thrown checkbox in the exception configuration dialog.  Debugging resource leaks, the most likely reason for this mishap is the other 90% of the project.

Comment: Is it possible there's an image resource that can't be resolved?

Comment: See [Winform has Red X exception](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17927128/winform-has-red-x-exception) article on the SO.